# Where\what is contact_form.urls?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am using [Django Contact Form](http://django-contact-form.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) within my application which requires the following addition to my urls.py file:

```
url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls'), name='contactform'),
```

What I don't understand is the `include()` function:

```
include('contact_form.urls')
```

Looking in the Django Docs, I thought that using `include()` refers to another URLconf module but
having looked over the file system I can't find anything with this name which leads me to believe that my understanding of include() is not correct?

So can you tell me what or where this "contact_form.urls" is?

In case of need I am using Django 1.6. on Xubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the python path.

Presumably, you installed `django contact form`, which would put `contact_form` in your python path.

If you can't find it in your *entire filesystem* you're not looking hard enough!

`python -c "import contact_form; print(contact_form.__file__)"` would be another way to find where this physically exists.

Comment: Perfect, thanks using your method I found it @ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/contact_form/urls.py. I'm brand new to python\django so asking this question and your answer has helped a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: @IanCarpenter no problem! Ultimately what packages are available to python is defined by what directories are in the python path `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`